Is there a way to set an upstream repository for an existing GitHub repo that was improperly uploaded and commited to?
i've been working on a small coding project with a few friends. In this project, they downloaded an open source online game (Space station 13, if you're curious) and uploaded their modifications to github as a new Repo. This works fine, but when working with original code, I cannot see history from the original game we downstreamed from, just showing as "Initial commit" since it was a source code uploaded opposed to properly downstreaming their repo. I am wondering, would it be possible to set the original repo as an upstream now, or would it be pretty much impossible at this point? (there's like 5 years of commits and I joined the group relatively recently.)
I've not tried anything myself besides looking up this question online, and found nothing myself that was useful. I dont actually have repo control access, but I do make PRs to it. I would probably need to walk them through what to do.

Just for the terminology: You don't set an upstream on a Git repository in GitHub. You only set an upstream on a local repository that you want to exchange data with a remote one, like e.g. one on GitHub.

Roughly the steps you would need to do are:

Create a new fork of the upstream repo and reset your HEAD to when you originally copied the repo's source, lets call this main
Bring in your repo as a new remote in this fork (multiple unrelated git histories can live in the same repository).
Cherry pick each of your changes onto the new main branch.

You won't be able to make this change as a PR though, you need admin access because this is basically a full reset and rewrites the entire history your original fork/copy made. All of the commits in this 5 year will get a new commit hash.
